# How do I ensure that gems are installed with permissions allowing all users to access them

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Whenever I install a gem I can only seem to do so using `sudo`. This typically leaves the permissions in a state that prevents me from being able to write scripts as a regular user which *don't* require `sudo`.

Do I need to fix permissions somewhere else to allow for the installation of gems for system-wide user access?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a tool to help you bundle gems, that information might be nice.  However, the `gem` command will let you do this, with the help of the gemspec that you should create.  Looking at [The Documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#executables) you can see the `executables` directive.  [Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/04/02/using-gemspecs-as-intended/) has a very good writeup on this, even though it is going on 4 years old.

Comment: I'm not using a tool. Simply running the `rails new` command which then prompts for my password. I'll look at the docs you've linked to and report back. In the meantime I've created a new VM and put `rvm` on it. Hopefully that will get me along.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: I don't always run `rails new`. When I posted this it was after simply running `gem install`. So basically, when running `rails new` the bundler requires my password to install everything as root and `gem install` requires `sudo` to install anything at all.

Comment: Now that you are using RVM you are not using 'sudo' at all, right?  Not for development.